# What would be the correct function to decode this string?

Tags: php, string, decode

Good evening everybody!

I'm stuck at writing my own email program in php for fun. I try to download all attachments from my email-address but some files have names like

> ISO-8859-15''%46%6C%79%65%72%20%53%61%69%73%6F%6E%65%72%F6%66

To decode the headers is used this function:

```
private function imap_header_decode($text) {
    $ret = "";
    $elements = imap_mime_header_decode($text);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($elements); $i++) {
        $ret .= utf8_decode($elements[$i]->text);
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

The headers are getting correctly decrypted while the file names don't. What could be the problem or better, how can I solve it?

EDIT: I used the imap_ functions from php for doing all the mail things (using pop3 with ssl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of encoding is called *url encoding* and it is defined in [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) ("URI syntax"). You can decode it with [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

Answer (score 1):

[`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) and [`rawurldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php).

> `rawurldecode()` does not decode plus symbols ('+') into spaces. `urldecode()` does.